# How to save unicode string in admin site django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to change data in admin site of django but when I save it, it will turn to something like 'C?a 4'. '?' is the unicode word. I have change data in database to utf8mb4 and if I change data directly in mysql, it will display properly in admin site. However, it can not display like i want if I change data in admin site of django. I'm using Python 3. This is my model

```
class Camera(models.Model):
camera_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
camera_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
stream_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'camera'

def __str__(self):
    return self.camera_name
```

Comment: To make sure I understand, you are receiving a unicode string and want to convert it to a 'normal' string before saving it to the database?

Comment: I want to save a unicode string to database but when i save it, it display with wrong way like I said before in database as well as on admin site of django. Sorry for bad English

Comment: I have edited the content of the topic, maybe you can understand my question now